# Email Alert when attaching the solution into the Case

Tags: workflow, case, email-alert

How do I send an email alert by using the workflow when attaching the solution into the case?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use triggers or workflow rules on case solutions at this time.

Some alternatives:

## Scheduled Apex

Have a process that runs on a timer, every few minutes, on the hour, etc, that checks for new case solutions since the last run, and sends emails for those cases/solutions.

## Visualforce

Create a Visualforce page for finding and attaching solutions. Have that code send the email when the solution is attached.

## Custom Object

Create a custom object that mimics the standard object. You can add a Visualforce page to search for solutions, etc, and a trigger to send the emails. Remember to make a standard case solution record in the trigger; this helps suggested solutions, etc.

## Manual

Most organizations prefer a manual approach to avoid accidents (e.g. selecting the wrong solution). You can create a template that the users can select to send the attached solutions on the case to the recipient.

Comment: Cant we achieve this in workflow or trigger?

Comment: @Alex We cannot. Unfortunately, there's no support for customizing Case Solutions at this time. That's why there's a list of workarounds.

Comment: do you have code for this. I am new in SFDC. please

Comment: Unable to follow above the comments could you please let me know step by procedure.

Comment: @Alex I'll update my answer just as soon as I write up an example.

Comment: Did you find the solution? :(